# How can I attach a RDS Instance to a Security Group in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm having a lot of trouble when trying to attach a security group to an rds instance in Terraform.
I was using the [aws_network_interface_sg_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_sg_attachment) resource to try to make the attachment, but since I am dealing with an RDS instance, I do not have the network interface id that I have on other instances to attach it to the SG.

How can I attach the RDS instances to a specific security group then?.

Bear in mind that I already have the RDS instance identifier, such as this one:

```
data "aws_db_instance" "example" {
 db_instance_identifier = "example-instance-1" }
```

Comment: Does the RDS exist outside of terraform? In this case you have to import it into terraform to modify its SG. Similarly if you want to modify existing SG created outside of terraform.

Comment: Yes it does, in Terraform I only have its identifier.
Can you provide an example about how I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change SG of an existing RDS which had been created outside of terraform (TF), you have to **import into TF** before you can modify it.

The import procedure is specific for a given use-case, thus its difficult to provide a valid example. However, you can read up **official guide** on doing this:

- [Import Terraform configuration](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/state-import)

The general steps would be (example):

1. Create a configuration corresponding to your rds

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
   engine   = "mysql"
   # other attributes
}
```

2. Execute `terraform import` to import existing db into the `aws_db_instance.db`.
3. Check with `terraform plan` the differences between your configuration and the actual state of the existing rds, and adjust if needed.

Once the RDS is under control of terraform you can modify it, e.g. its **security group**. But since this is RDS, please **be careful** and make sure to have backup of the RDS. Mistakes can lead to more troubles, e.g. accidental changes or deletion of a production database. Thus it would be good idea to **try and test** the approach on some **test database**, e.g. replica of the real RDS.

Comment: He is asking for specific example to attach a security group to rds instance. Not for importing.